# What is the best way to replicate an out of disk space condition in a test environment?

Tags: directory, mount, quota, dd

I want to replicate a quota issue. a process write to a file in a directory and that we ran out of disk space, process writes empty file due to that.

I want to replicate that on my dev machine. Does anyone know how to specify quota limit on a directory?

I was thinking this way 
create a directory
make sure that process write to this directory or mount the directory to directory on which that process write.
let the process do a huge write on a file to that directory

Answer (score 1):

Quotas work on users and groups, so if you want to use the quota system you should probably create a test user.

However, it is probably easier to simulate the problem by making a small RAM disk and mounting that. Then run your program in the RAM disk. Either wait until it fills up, or dump bytes into a file on the mounted ramdisk until it runs out of space.